# Erro Conectar ao banco de Dados?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Bom estou tentando fazer uma conexão a um banco de dados e esta dando o seguinte erro

> "ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on
>   '167.114.173.210' (13)"

E eu tenho um programa **"Navicat"**  e por ele eu consigo acessar essa DB, apenas para fazer a conexão com o site ate a DB que esta dando esse erro, ja conferi e esta tudo certo... Alguém sabe o porque esta dando isso ?

---

No meu pc estou usando o wamp e esta dando esse erro 
[image: PDO Exception]

Já na vps onde o site ira ficar da este erro

[image: Can't connect to MySQL server]

Agora no navicat

[image: Connection successfull]

Comment: Já verificou se os usuário, senha, porta e host estão corretos?

Comment: @ValdeirPsr, sim como eu disse eu testei no Navicat e por la a conexão faz de boa

Comment: Estou hospedando o site em uma vps linux e a db em outro lugar

Comment: Como está seu arquivo de conexão? Lembre-se. Alguns servidores não permitem o mesmo nome do seu local. Por exemplo: local: db_dados no servidor: ZL_DB_DADOS